# What's the reason that we can't log in to the the RaspPi via USB cable?

Tags: usb, login

I just got my CHIP today, and can't help being impressed with how much easier it is to get started with, than faffing with the RaspPi, extra HDMI screen, keyboard. mouse etc.

I just plugged it into the serial port of my laptop, found a terminal program and logged in.

What I want to know is why the RaspPi can't do this? What were the design constraints that meant that we can't make an equivalent serial-over-USB connection to it? And is there hope that a later model of RaspPi might bring this feature?

It seems a hugely unnecessary extra hurdle to doing much work with the RaspPi.

Comment: Well you can actually log in using a serial port... it's just not via USB but a simple UART with its pins routed to the extension header. On a side note many current laptops don't even provide a serial port anymore. Still, with the Pi you could say *just plugged it into the ethernet port, found a terminal program and logged in*.

Comment: Yes. But it's not a "simple UART" if I don't have one hanging around the house. UART is specialist equipment. A microUSB isn't. It's just how I charge my phone. My real question though is why doesn't RaspPi do this?

Comment: Barring comments from the RPi Foundation you're unlikely to get a satisfactory answer as to the design reasoning. If I had to guess, it would be cost. Most Pi models' micro USB sockets are only wired to receive +5V and ground from the cable - no data. Adding the components, traces and logic to deal with the Pi acting as a USB OTG device would be more expensive than the current option.

Comment: @goobering Sure. But CHIP manages it, and its only $9. So I suspect it's a design decision / trade-off rather than absolute impossibility. Having just realized how useful it is to be able to do this, I was wondering why this trade off was made.

Comment: Comparing the CHIP with Raspberry Pi is like comparing the Spectrum ZX80 with an IBM PC

Answer (score 4):

USB is not a symmetrical protocol, meaning, it is not peer to peer the way, e.g., IP networking is (it might be considered to resemble higher level client-server network protocols).

A USB hub/controller (they are internal) and the ports connected to it (the jacks you see) are either *masters* (aka. hosts) or *slaves* (aka. clients).  A slave connects to a master.  A master does not connect to another master, and a slave does not connect to another slave (there is a sort of exception to this, keep reading).

Because connecting two masters together can cause potential damage due to the fact that part of the master-slave relation is that the master may provide power, usually master ports are the standard size jack you find on your computer or laptop, and slave ports are smaller (mini or micro), although this is not necessary.  Some have [OTG capability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go), allowing them to act as slave or (a sort of) master; smartphones and tablets often have this, as does the Pi Zero, which *can* be connected directly to a normal computer host port (although it's used to mimic an ethernet, not UART serial connection).

You probably have not communicated from your laptop to your desktop via USB for the reasons already mentioned.  First, it will never work, and second, it may damage one or the other permanently.  Note that there are special USB cables that will allow you to circumvent this but they are an oddity and not well (or: not at all) supported on the Pi.

Other than the Zero, Pi USB jacks are like those on a normal computer (I believe the A/A+ may also be used in OTG client mode) -- they are masters and cannot be connected to another master.  This makes them more useful for general purposes, such as connecting slave devices like keyboards, mice, hard drives, etc.

Comment: OK. That makes sense. Does this mean that with the Zero I can just login via USB cable?

Comment: It mimics an "ethernet gadget", meaning it is basically like connecting two computers together with an ethernet cable (which you can also do with a normal Pi -- but the Zero does not have an ethernet jack).  I.e., it's a normal network but there are only two nodes, so you can, e.g., `ssh` in.